# Change class of DOM element using ngClass

Tags: angular

In Angular2, I want to change the class of tr to 'success' if video.encodings.length>0. It seems the following does not work. The expression of ngClass can bind to data var?

```
 <tr *ngFor="#video of _videos" [ngClass]="success : {{ video.encodings.length >0 }}">
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The syntax for `ngClass` should be

```
<tr *ngFor="#video of _videos" [ngClass]="{success : video.encodings.length > 0 }">
```